# Remove the show and disappear feature from the numeric keypad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Using a JSfiddle I found online I am displaying a numeric keypad. ATM the keypad appears and disappears as the user clicks the input button.

I would like to remove this feature from the script code, allowing the keypad to be visible at all times, but am unsure which part to remove from the code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myInput').click(function () {
            $('#n_keypad').fadeToggle('fast');
        });
        $('.done').click(function () {
            $('#n_keypad').hide('fast');
        });
        $('.numero').click(function () {
            if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val())) {
                if (parseInt($('#myInput').val()) == 0) {
                    $('#myInput').val($(this).text());
                } else {
                    $('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val() + $(this).text());
                }
            }
        });
        $('.neg').click(function () {
            if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val()) && $('#myInput').val().length > 0) {
                if (parseInt($('#myInput').val()) > 0) {
                    $('#myInput').val(parseInt($('#myInput').val()) - 1);
                }
            }
        });
        $('.pos').click(function () {
            if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val()) && $('#myInput').val().length > 0) {
                $('#myInput').val(parseInt($('#myInput').val()) + 1);
            }
        });
        $('.del').click(function () {
            $('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val().substring(0, $('#myInput').val().length - 1));
        });
        $('.clear').click(function () {
            $('#myInput').val('');
        });
        $('.zero').click(function () {
            if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val())) {
                if (parseInt($('#myInput').val()) != 0) {
                    $('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val() + $(this).text());
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
Also, the keypad appears on the left, how can I align it to the right. I dont see any ref to alignment in the code?

Comment: CAn you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a fiddle it'll be easier to help. By the looks of it, it seems to be these lines

```
$('#n_keypad').fadeToggle('fast');
});
$('.done').click(function () {
            $('#n_keypad').hide('fast');
});
```

The alignment I believe is done using CSS. You'll have to provide the markup or create a fiddle.

Comment: how can i right align it?, it appears on the left of the screen and i dont see any ref to alignment

Comment: @John Like I said, for that you'll have to create a fiddle/provide the markup.

Comment: well the keypad is displayed inside a table. iv set the table to style="float: right;" and that appears at the furthest point right it can go, i Would like it about 3/4 of the way right?

Comment: To set an element right. you can use all sorts of stuff. Here's one using absolute positioning http://jsfiddle.net/cFhKy/